# Extract month and year from Date and display as MMM-YY

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new to google apps script, I am having a hard time with date format conversion

my source column has data in the format  "mm/dd/yyyy". I would like to change this to "MMM-YY" i.e. I just need to extract Month and year. 
 Below is my unsuccessful attempt

```
 // Get all values in column A on sheet titled "Transactions"
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

var sourcesheet = ss.getSheetByName("Transactions");
var targetsheet = ss.getSheetByName("stage");  

  // get source range
  var source = sourcesheet.getRange("A:J");
  //get the data and place in array
  var alldata = sourcesheet.getRange("A:I").getValues();
  Logger.log(alldata.length)  ;

  //********************************************************************************//
  // loop through date column and change format
 for(var i=1; i<alldata.length; i++)    
  {

    alldata[i][0]= new Date(alldata[i][0]);

    var Mnth = alldata[i][0].getMonth() ;
    var Year = alldata[i][0].getYear() ;
    var Day = alldata[i][0].getDay() ;

    var Day2 = new Date(Year,Mnth,Day);

    alldata[i][10] = Utilities.formatDate(Day2, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MMM-YY");


  }


  //********************************************************************************//
  // get destination range  
  var destination = targetsheet.getRange(2, 1, alldata.length, 11);

  // clear contents of destination sheet
  destination.clear();
  // copy values to destination range
  destination.setValues(alldata);

}
```

Example

Source column value = "01/06/2019" value written to output column "1/19/2019" but it displays as "Jan-19"

Comment: Can you please describe why it's unsuccessful? What is it doing wrong?

Comment: Example 

Source column value = "01/06/2019"
value written to output column "1/19/2019" but it displays as "Jan-19"

Comment: formatDate is going to return a string completely foreign to google sheets as a date, why don't you just set the formatting INSIDE the spreadsheet to display the format you want?

Comment: @CodeCamper I was hoping to automate this, since the number of rows in the source spreadsheet will vary over time and I want to remove manual steps

Comment: @bodhi Why not set set the spreadsheet date format in the script instead of sending a string foreign to google sheets?

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
alldata[i][10] = Utilities.formatDate(Day2, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MMM-YY");
```

by

```
alldata[i][10] = "'" + Utilities.formatDate(Day2, ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "MMM-yy");
```

Explanation

1. Prepend  an apostrophe to prevent that Google Sheets from interpreting the values of the form `MMM-YY` as `MMM-dd`
2. Replace `YY` by `yy`
3. Replace `Session.getScriptTimeZone()` by `ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone()`

NOTES

1. `YY` means *weak year* that could lead to some errors in certain dates of the year. To prevent this, instead use `yy`.
2. Some letters used for date format in Google Sheets and in Google Apps Script could mean different things. See the references to use them properly.
3. The script time zone and the spreadsheet time zone could be different. Since you will passing the values to the spreadsheet, it's better to use its time zone instead of the one from the script.

---

The solution to get the dates displayed as `MMM-yy` as date values instead of text (string) values, doesn't require to use Google Apps Script, instead use the Google Sheets number format feature (click on Format > Number > More Formats > More date and time formats), well you could use Google Apps Script to set the number format by using [`setNumberFormat(numberFormat)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnumberformatnumberformat)

References

Date and Number Formats

In Google Sheets

- https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats

In `Utilities.formatDate(date,timezone,format)`

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: AFAIK there is no difference between `YY` and `yy` while there is between `MM` (months) and `mm` (minutes).

Comment: @Rubén you solution works, it generates a string ex 'Dec-19. Are there any options as getting the output in date and not string?

Answer (score 1):

This works with the format as `MMM-yy`

```
function myFunction1() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ssh=ss.getSheetByName("Transactions");
  var tsh=ss.getSheetByName("stage");  
  var srg=ssh.getRange(1,1,ssh.getLastRow(),11);
  var data=srg.getValues();
  data.forEach(function(r,i){r[10]=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(data[i][0]),Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MMM-yy");});
  var destination=tsh.getRange(1,1,data.length,11);
  destination.clear();
  destination.setValues(data);
}
```

[reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 0):

You just copy date values to the target sheet without any changes whatsoever and the apply custom number format to the target range.

```
var datesRange = sheet.getRange("A1:A");
var values = datesRange.getValues();
var destination = targetSheet.getRange("A1:A");
destination.setValues(values).setNumberFormat("mmm-yy");
```

As Ruben pointed out, you can simply change the number format in UI (no need for scripting) so his solution is probably the best one.