# AutoPopulating date from Sheet to Doc and getting a different timezone (GoogleScript)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm autopopulating a document from the information in a sheet, all works well besides the date, which comes a day earlier. From my understanding it's because a different timezone is applied.

Ideal situation, the date shows up dd.mm.yyyy without the hour and timezone, and I'm not figuring it out.

The function creates a new google doc with the populated information, saves it and saves the link back into the sheet.

```
const Signingdate = new Date(row[5]).toLocaleDateString();
const Startdate = new Date(row[6]).toLocaleDateString();
const Enddate = new Date(row[7]).toLocaleDateString();

body1.replaceText('{{Candidate Name}}', row[38]);
body1.replaceText('{{Candidate Address}}', row[22]);
body1.replaceText('{{Job Title}}', row[13]);
body1.replaceText('{{Job Tasks}}', row[39]);
body1.replaceText('{{Hiring Manager Name}}', row[11]);
body1.replaceText('{{Hiring Manager Email Address}}', row[43]);
body1.replaceText('{{Hiring Manager Phone Number}}', row[44]);
body1.replaceText('{{Candidate Email Address}}', row[24]);
body1.replaceText('{{Candidate Phone Number}}', row[23]);
body1.replaceText('{{Candidate Remote Rate}}', row[28]);
body1.replaceText('{{Candidate Onsite Rate}}', row[40]);
body1.replaceText('{{Candidate Start Date}}', Signingdate);
body1.replaceText('{{Candidate End Date}}', Enddate);
body1.replaceText('{{Signing Date}}', Signingdate);
```

Answer (score 1):

`toLocaleDateString()` will return the date according to the locale set in Google servers. Instead use [`Intl.DateTimeFormat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat) or [`Utilities.dateFormat()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format). Both allows you to set your own timezone.

Related

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/59277995/1595451
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/59895802/1595451